# Discrete math - Pascal

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$  s.t. $n > 4.$ Prove  the following is true:

[image]

Those kind of proofs which I have no idea where to start at. It seems more "tricky" to me and I would like to some advice where I should start. I know it is probably manipulating the binomial formula

Comment: so for $n=2$ you have $2^4-{2 \choose  1} \cdot 1^4=0$. That is not true

Comment: Have you encountered induction before? Try showing that the statement holds for $n=5$ and then arguing that if it holds for a given $n$ then it necessarily holds for $n+1$.

Comment: This property is connected to the theory of divided differences (a discrete equivalent of differentials), here of function $k^4$ for $k=1 \cdots n$ : the fact that it is $0$ for exponent $4$ but for none of the exponents before $4$ is in full analogy with the fact that the successive derivatives of polynomial x^4 are non-identically zero till order $4$ but are identically $0$ above $4$. If I have time, I will write an answer explaining that.

Answer (score 1):

For a combinatorial proof: consider leaving the $n^4$ on the one side and moving everything else to the other side of the equation.  Answer the question "*How many ways can $4$ distinct balls be placed in $n$ distinct boxes?*" in two ways.

The first way, answer directly.  This is simply $n^4$.

The second way, answer the question of how many ways it could be done if at least one of the boxes remained empty (*which is guaranteed in the case of $n>4$, remember*) and approach by inclusion-exclusion over the events "*The first box is empty*", "*The second box is empty*" and so on.  This gives the rest of the expression.

Since both correctly count the same scenario, they must be equal.

They failed to be equal for $n\leq 4$ because there exist ways to distribute the four balls resulting in no empty boxes.  There is only guaranteed at least one empty box when there were more boxes than balls.